# Calculate the average of values in B2:B based on the uniqueness of A2:A, then display it on a column (C2:C) (Google Sheets; spreadsheet)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to calculate averages of the B2:B matrix based on the uniqueness of the values in A2:A. I added an image to clear this up:
[image]

I have tried something like this, but can't go past the AVERAGE() function and what to do there.

```
=BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:A); LAMBDA(a; AVERAGE()))
```

Comment: I'd rather not use QUERY function if possible BTW

Comment: @SolarMike useless action just because of my username, still it's a spreadsheet problem so don't worry bud

Comment: Some functions don't exist in Excel that exist in Googlesheets and while some do, they don't always work the same. As you say "don't worry bud"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try-

```
=LET(
x,A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),
y,B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(A2:A)),
z,UNIQUE(x),
a,BYROW(z,LAMBDA(t,AVERAGEIFS(y,x,t))),
HSTACK(z,a))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No LAMBDA needed for this one:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B2:B8,A2:A8,UNIQUE(A2:A8))
or
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A8),AVERAGEIFS(B2:B8,A2:A8,UNIQUE(A2:A8)))
```

[image]

Comment: first example doesn't work on spreadsheet by making columns and the second one only represents the first unique value, the rest are #N/A

Comment: Sounds like you don't have Excel 365.